# Get the title of a Pull Request from command line

Tags: git, github, jenkins, terminal, ghprb

I'm writing a continuous integration step that checks the titles of our pull requests for proper tags and formatting before allowing them to be merged.

To do this, I need to echo the title of the Pull Request when given the PR number. Is there a way to do this simply in command line?

Comment: What is your central server? every server store it under a different refspec

Comment: We are using Github as our central server.

Answer (score 5):

building off of @Simon-Warta's answer you can do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/user_org/project.git
pushd project
for pr in $(git log --pretty="%s" --merges | grep pull | sed -e "s/.*#\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g" | sort -rn | uniq); do
  curl https://api.github.com/repos/user_org/project/pulls/${pr} 2>/dev/null | jq '.title';
done
popd
```

You'll need `curl` and `jq` available on your machine but that shouldn't be hard if you have a reasonable linux distro..

Answer (score 5):

With Github's new official [CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (command line interface):

```
gh pr view 3 --repo OWNER/REPO | head -n 1
```

where:

- `3` is the PR number
- `gh pr view [options]` displays the title (first line), body, and other information about the PR
- `head -n 1` only keeps the first line of the `gh pr view` output in order to only get the title

See additional [details and options](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view) and [installation instructions](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation).

Answer (score 2):

For pull requests use

`https://api.github.com/repos/randombit/botan/pulls/359`

For patches in a pull request, search for `Subject:` in the `.patch` url:

`https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/359.patch`

Note that you can only do [60 request per hour and IP](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) on the Github API.

Comment: The patch url does contain a subject line with the PR title, however when I edit the title and then look at the patch url again, it still contains the old title.

Comment: @DannyDelott, right, because the subject is the commit message(s), not the PR title. PR data is not part of the Git system but Github specific meta data. So you'll nee to take their API if commit messages are not okay for you.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks **Kevin Kreiser**.
My version of his solution without **jq** & only **current commits** from **last tag**.

### TL;DR

*instead*

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/user_org/project/pulls/${pr} 2>/dev/null | jq '.title';`

*use*

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/user_org/project/pulls/${pr} | grep title | cut -d'"' -f4`

### For **CocoaHeadsRu repository example**:

```
git clone https://github.com/cocoaheadsru/application.git  // clone the repository
cd application           // go to the application folder
touch getTitles.sh       // create file getTitles.sh
chmod a+x getTitles.sh   // make the file executable
vi getTitles.sh          // open the file in the vim text editor
```

**add** the following **code** to the **getTitles.sh**:

```
for pr in $(git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --pretty="%s" --merges | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'#' -f2 | tr '\n' ' ')
do
    curl https://api.github.com/repos/cocoaheadsru/application/pulls/${pr} | grep title | cut -d'"' -f4
done
```

**save** the **code** and **exit** the **vim**

```
:wq
```

Now we can **create** a **release notes file** using our **script**:

```
./getTitles.sh > ReleaseNotes.txt
cat ReleaseNotes.txt

// [qXUdCQay] Changed app build number, deleted MARKETING_VERSION and CU…
// Feature/kn vl5 eaw/add bluetooth always key
// [CQoos82f] Updated Realm, increment app version
// upgraded travis configuration
// Открытие места проведения митапа в 2ГИС
// Автокапитализация и технические улучшения
// Интеграция Travis-CI
// Postpone fetchEvents for main view after view appearing
```

#### Description script code:

#### 1

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0                  // get the last tag
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD // get all commit from last tag to HEAD
[--//--] --pretty="%s"                          // all commits in one line
[--//--] --merges                               // merged commits only
```

#### 2

**break** the **string** into parts using the **space character** and get **4th value**

ex *Merge pull request **#347** from antonsergeev88/swipeToPop_crash*

```
[--//--] cut -d' ' -f4      // get '#347'
```

#### 3

**break** the **string** into parts using the **'#' character** and get **2nd value**

ex *#**347***

```
[--//--] cut -d'#' -f2      // get '347'
```

#### 4

```
tr '\n' ' '                 // replaced '/n' with a space character
```

we get something like **355 354 353 352 350 349 348 347**

#### 5

In the **loop** using **github api**:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/cocoaheadsru/application/pulls/347
```

we **get all pull requests** in **json-format**. One of them:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/cocoaheadsru/application/pulls/347",
  "id": 215781239,
  "number": 347,
  "state": "closed",
  ...
  "title": "Postpone fetchEvents for main view after view appearing",
  ...
  "user": {...},
  "merged_at": "2018-09-30T17:26:47Z",
  "merge_commit_sha": "553d8ea6f189882a22d424d0770785b53ddc4ab4",
  "commits": 1,
  ...
}
```

#### 6

using **grep**

```
[--//--] | grep title
```

**get** a **line** with the word **title**:

```
"title": "Postpone fetchEvents for main view after view appearing",
```

#### 7

using **cut**:

```
[--//--] | cut -d'"' -f4
```

**finally** we **get** only **title value**:

```
Postpone fetchEvents for main view after view appearing
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using github:

Locate the section for your github remote in the `.git/config` file. It looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:a.git
```

Now add the line `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to this section. Obviously, change the github url to match your project's URL. It ends up looking like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:a.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Now fetch all the pull requests:

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:ja
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1000/head -> origin/pr/1000
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1002/head -> origin/pr/1002
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1004/head -> origin/pr/1004
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1009/head -> origin/pr/1009
```

To check out a particular pull request:

```
$ git checkout pr/999
Branch pr/999 set up to track remote branch pr/999 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'pr/999'
```

Comment: In your example, how would one access the title of `pr/999`?

Comment: Get the sha-1 from the file (pr) and use git show to print it. Im not sure if it will print the commit message or the PR title. need to give it a shoot

Comment: Unfortunately this shows the commit message, not the PR title.